# parsing jsonpath with kubectl

Tags: json, kubernetes

In my setup I have two Pods. Each running a single container with busybox image.

I want to parse Pod name and its container's image name using Kubectl. First I tried to get these fields individually. That works fine. Then I tried to combine 'Pod name' with 'dns policy' field. And that also works. But if I try to combine the 'Pod name' and 'container image' fields, then I am getting the error.

Could you please help me understand why I am getting error with final command?

Thanks,

```
test-cloud@user1-c1-cp1:~$ k get pods -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}"
busybox busybox

test-cloud@user1-c1-cp1:~$
test-cloud@user1-c1-cp1:~$ k get pods -o jsonpath="{.items[*]['.metadata.name']}"
b2 b4

test-cloud@user1-c1-cp1:~$ k get pods -o jsonpath="{.items[*]['.metadata.name', '.spec.dnsPolicy']}"
b2 b4 ClusterFirst ClusterFirst

test-cloud@user1-c1-cp1:~$ k get pods -o jsonpath="{.items[*]['.metadata.name}" '.spec.containers[*].image']}
error: error parsing jsonpath {.items[*]['.metadata.name', '.spec.containers[*].image']}, invalid array index '.spec.containers[*
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to keep it simple by using `custom-columns`:

```
kubectl get pod -o custom-columns="POD-NAME":.metadata.name,"NAMESPACE":.metadata.namespace,"CONTAINER-IMAGES":.spec.containers[*].image,"DNS-POLICY":.spec.dnsPolicy
POD-NAME   NAMESPACE   CONTAINER-IMAGES   DNS-POLICY
bar        default     nginx              ClusterFirst
foo        default     nginx              ClusterFirst
zoo        default     nginx,ubuntu       ClusterFirst
```

Using `jsonpath`:

```
kubectl get pod -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name},{.spec.containers[*].image},{.spec.dnsPolicy}{"\n"}{end}'
bar,nginx,ClusterFirst
foo,nginx,ClusterFirst
zoo,nginx ubuntu,ClusterFirst
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. While posted answers would work, I found below more suitable:

```
k get pods -o jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata.name}, {.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}"
```

b2 b4, busybox busybox